# How can I extend a Retrofit 2.0 Call?

Tags: retrofit

I want to achieve something like this:

```
MyCall<MyResponse> call = service.login(loginRequest);

call.enqueue(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // onResponse
            }
        }, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // onFailure
            }
    });
```

so that when I have to make a call I don't need to parse the response in each callback and the code is a little lighter and reusable.

I tried the code from [this snippet](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1059#issuecomment-139455974) but I get the error:

**Unable to create call adapter for XXXX.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not extend `Call` but I extend `Callback`, it's also help to make `the code is a little lighter and reusable.`

```
public abstract class CustomCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Response<T> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onRequestSuccess(response);
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable t) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onRequestFail(t);
            }
        };
        runnable.run();

    }

    public abstract void onRequestSuccess(Response<T> response);

    public abstract void onRequestFail(Throwable t);

}
```

Then when you call `enqueue()`:

```
call.enqueue(new CustomCallback<YourObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestSuccess(final Response<YourObject> response)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestFail(final Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this would be exactly what I was looking for. The code with retrofit 2 is a little different, but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the snippet below Jake Wharton's post then the issue should be that you're including a call to `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()` & your call interface is not an observable. So remove that line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, that was the first thing that I had tried but I still had the same error. I'm new to retrofit so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.