# Retrofit Generic Base Method for request

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a problem with `Retrofit` and duplicate checking.
I have to check every time `response` status code or type!

I need a `wrapper` for request method that checks there this duplicate works.
(duplicate works includes: `showLoading()`,`response.code()`,`onFailure()` handle...).

I need a `GenericMethod` for this:

```
UserService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(UserService.class);

service.RequestVerification(token, mobileNumber).enqueue(new Callback<ClientData<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ClientData<User>> call, @NonNull Response<ClientData<User>> response) {
                doAction();//Action must passed to this method.
                GeneralTools.hideLoading();               
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ClientData<User>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
             GeneralTools.hideLoading();
             dialogError.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: duplicate works ?? please simplify your requirement

Comment: I need check response.code() if it is 401 handle user to login again for example. I must check it everytime in all requests OnResponse()?! I need check it once time in base method or other thing. @KrishnaSharma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302889/how-can-i-extend-a-retrofit-2-0-call?answertab=active#tab-top this would be your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
private static class CallbackHandler<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        int code = response.code();
        if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
            onSuccess(response);
        } else if (code == 401) {
            // logic to refresh token or user then recall the same api
            call.clone().enqueue(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

    }

    public void onSuccess(Response<T> response) {

    }

}
```

Then change your call like below

```
service.RequestVerification(token, mobileNumber).enqueue(new CallbackHandler<ClientData<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Response<ClientData<User>> response) {
        doAction();//Action must passed to this method.
        GeneralTools.hideLoading();               
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ClientData<User>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
     GeneralTools.hideLoading();
     dialogError.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Krishna, in Step 2 Retrofit 2.0 Service method cannot return void, what's your solution  for Retrofit 2?

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour That's not the actual service/retrofit interface method call, that is a wrapper method at the client side which will call internally actual service/retrofit interface method call. **Look at the updated answer**

Comment: requestVerification (Step 2) Where should I be defined ?!

Comment: Step 2 and 5 should be at UI level for example activity or fragment

Comment: That was the proper way of doing, no worries have updated the answer as per your need.